# Single store multi-currency setup issue with import rate Magento2

Tags: magento2, import, multicurrency, currency-rates

I am having issue in import rate for currency.
Default currency is US Dollar and the other currency what I want is Indian Rupee.

Import Rate options are not working.

Comment: Which API are you using for import?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, I am using magento's default Yahoo and WebserviceX option from the drop down given, but both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, all the 3 web services for currency rates import in Magento 2 don't work.

Please see the results below:

> Yahoo Finance Exchange:

[image: yahoo Magento Error]

When you hit the URL shown in the error, you see the following:

[image: yahoo API URL Error]

> Webservicex:

[image: Webservicex Magento Error]

When you hit the URL shown in the error, you see the following:

[image: Webservicex API URL Error]

> Fixer.io:

[image: Fixer.io Magento Error]

When you hit the URL shown in the error, you see the following:

[image: Fixer.io API URL Error]

If you want to use Fixer.io service, you will be required to create an account at https://fixer.io and obtain an API access key.

Please read more [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtBdA.png).

Alternatively, you can check other ways to integrate currency conversion [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAElc.png) (to integrate **Free Currency Converter API**) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS034.png) (to use **Fixer.io paid API**).